# Alternatives for stick in one's mind

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am writing a motivation letter for an American graduate school and want it to be as formal as possible. I came across with **stick in one's mind**.

> My professor has been stuck in my mind due to his great style of
>   teaching.

Is there any formal synonym/alternative which connotes the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how fulsome you want to be. Some possibilities that occur to me are:

> - made a great impression
> - made an unforgettable impression
> - has been a standing inspiration

Comment: Never thought of "impression". It's, indeed, a good choice at this point. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my intemperance tone here, the expression "formal writing" does imply you are obliged to annoy your audience by attempting to prove you are smarter than they. High-quality formal writers employ simple words and simple sentences when those suffice for their needs.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Simplicity is the most important things in such writings. But I think it is really not a good idea to use idioms/slangs, even though they may have a direct connotation, in a formal writing.

Comment: Slang not. Simple idioms with **exactly** the right meaning? I would, but then I write fiction.